# How to handle invalid state in redux reducer

Tags: redux

I have an action that is dispatched when a user attempts to login and the request is still pending:

```
function signinRequestReducer(state, action) {
    if (action.type === "SIGNIN_REQUEST") {
        state = {signingIn: true};
    }
    return state;
}
```

However what happens if this is initiated twice (due to a bug elsewhere in the code).  Should the reducer ignore the second action (and remain a pure function), should it throw an Error (and no longer be a pure function), or something else?

```
function signinRequestReducer(state, action) {
    if (action.type === "SIGNIN_REQUEST") {
        if (state.signingIn) {
            // Option 1
            return state;
            // Option 2
            raise new Error("Can not sign in whilst pending previous attempt.");
            // Option 3 ... ?
        }
        state = {signingIn: true};
    }
    return state;
}
```

** **edit** **

For the time being I'm logging an error.

```
if (action.type === "SIGNIN_REQUEST") {
    if (state.signingIn) {
        console.error("Can not sign in whilst pending previous attempt.");
        // return state; // only return early if it's really not possible to set the new state.
    }
    ...
```

This isn't a pure function but it does allow:

- the error to be observed in development and production.
- should the invalid state / dispatched actions still allow the app to function it will still be able to do so.

** **edit 2** **

[Dan Abramov suggested](https://mobile.twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/857566548034293765) to throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log an error.

```
if (action.type === "SIGNIN_REQUEST") {
    if (state.signingIn) {
        console.error("Can not sign in whilst pending previous attempt.");
        // return state; // only return early if it's really not possible to set the new state.
    }
    ...
```

This isn't a pure function but it does allow:

- the error to be observed in development and production.
- should the invalid state / dispatched actions still allow the app to function it will still be able to do so.

Dan Abramov suggested to throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, in this example, is there any harm in just letting the action occur twice? All that will happen is `signingIn` will be set to `true` again, which doesn't seem like the worst thing that can happen.

There definitely are times when you don't want duplicate actions coming through, so I'll continue the answer below.

---

When it comes to duplicate actions, I prefer to prevent the actions from being dispatched at all, rather than swallowing the it in the reducer.

Generally speaking, it is asynchronous actions, such a api requests, that we want to protect from this kind of behaviour and this approach not only stops the state from being updated multiple times, but also stops the actual work from happening twice.  Using an async middleware, such as [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) can provide some useful tools to do this.

In redux-thunk, there is a second parameter to the thunk that allows you to check access the state.  If, like in your example, you set a flag in the state before the async request begins, you can use the to bail out of the thunk before the second action is event started.

```
const signIn = (/* your parameters here */) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  if (getState().path.to.signingIn) {
    // console.error or throw Error here if you prefer
    return;
  }

  dispatch({ type: 'SIGNIN_REQUEST' });

  // do sign in
}
```

**Note:** redux-thunk can be used in this way for synchronous actions as well (in fact, that is what I have shown in my example).

I'm not very familiar with redux-saga, but there seems to be a [pretty standard pattern for only taking the first action](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/589#issuecomment-259346425).

Comment: "I prefer to prevent the actions from being dispatched at all" I agree.  But when you're programming defensively what do you do?  i.e. you write a reducer knowing that if it gets called twice, the state will be invalid, or if when it is called, it checks the current state and finds it's invalid, what do you do?  "Generally speaking, it is asynchronous actions, such a api requests, that we want to protect from this kind of behaviour" - it's all actions, but as most are from async events (api, user, timing, etc) then yes I suppose it is.

Comment: Thanks for the examples of redux-thunk.  But again it's not what I'm asking. "How to handle invalid state in redux reducer".  I appreciate that the code outside the reducers is where is should be handled and if it's not then it's a bug.  But I'm wondering about what is best practice **within a reducer function**.  Anyway, the "solution" in the edit of the question: calling `console.error()` and allowing he reducer to continue / abort early if definitely it doesn't make sense to change the state, works fine at the moment.  Thanks for your answer.